# Need help in animating a Wheel on iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, touch, drag, image-rotation

I am doing an application in iphone that need to spin the Dart Wheel when I drag on it. The view will have a dart wheel image and when we drag the wheel it spins and slowly it stops.

Can any one help me in doing this animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoreAnimation for the rotation animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[view.layer setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You will have to tweak the animation for your needs.